# Alloy: Is it possible to retrieve "instances" that make at least one constraint false

Tags: alloy

I've used Alloy always in the same way: either to find instances (solutions) for a given set of constraints (= model) or to check particular properties of the model that can be expressed as assertions (checks are performed in order to search for counter examples). However, there is a new requirement which cause my two questions:

1. Is it possible to retrieve all assignments of relations to variables that DO NOT fulfill the constraints contained in the Alloy model? This means I want to collect all examples that are not a solution of the given Alloy model.
2. If yes: How can I do this?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If `pred` is set of constraints to your model, then `run {!pred}` will find all instances that violate those constraints.

Comment: And if your model is written with non-`pred` constraints (e.g. facts), and you want instances which violate those constraints?  Rewrite them as `pred`, and see the answer above.